# grunt serve fails to run due to clean:server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I intstalled my app properly via yeoman and an angular generator. Whenever I run `grunt serve` I get the following warning when Running `"clean:server" (clean) task`: `Warning: Cannot delete files outside the current working directory. Use --force to continue.`

The app works fine when I run `grunt serve -force` or by removing the `.tmp/` folder with `rm -r .tmp/`. This is however not so nice and I would like to solve this problem without creating a new app from scratch. Is this possible?

The warning is a bit strange to me as the .tmp/ folder is in my app folder, and it used to work fine. Could this be due to an older version of NPM? I noticed that I got an older version by re-installing npm via brew.

Comment: The older version of NPM does not seem to be the problem after installing the latest version the problem still occurs. However I found out that the .tmp folder contains a style sheet that is not used (or not that i can remember), could this be the problem?

Comment: 1. Try check the permission on the directories, specifically `.tmp`. 
2. Try updating `npm` version.
3. Check if your `node` version is compatible with generator you are using.